# Why do torchvision.transforms.Resize and tensorflow.image.resize_images get different results

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, torchvision

I tried to resize the same tensor with these two functions. The interpolation method I'm using is bilinear and I don't understand why I'm getting a different output

I have tried my test code as follows:

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn 

size_psc = 128

torch.manual_seed(123)
x0 = torch.randn(torch.Size([1, 64, 502, 502]))

#using torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
resize = transforms.Resize((size_psc, size_psc))
torch_resize_out = resize(x0)

#using tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf_x0 = x0.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous()
tf_resize = tf.image.resize_images(tf_x0, (size_psc, size_psc), 0)
sess = tf.Session()
tf_resize_out = sess.run(tf_resize)
sess.close()
tf_resize_out = torch.Tensor(tf_resize_out)
tf_resize_out = tf_resize_out.permute(0, 3, 1, 2).contiguous()

assert torch.max(abs(torch_resize_out - tf_resize_out)) < 1e-5
```

The requirements I use are as follows:
torchvision (0.11.2)
torch (1.10.1)
tensorflow (1.10.0)

I want to get the same result. However, the results of these two functions are obviously different.I don't understand why both use bilinear interpolation but get different results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meh, your code must be quite old.
I tried this in colab and no error. They are identical.

```
import torch 
import torch.nn as nn 

size_psc = 128

torch.manual_seed(123)
x0 = torch.randn(torch.Size([1, 64, 502, 502]))

#using torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
resize = transforms.Resize((size_psc, size_psc))
torch_resize_out = resize(x0)

#using tensorflow
import tensorflow as tf
tf_x0 = x0.permute(0, 2, 3, 1).contiguous()
tf_resize = tf.image.resize(tf_x0, (size_psc, size_psc))
tf_resize_out = tf_resize.numpy()
tf_resize_out = torch.Tensor(tf_resize_out)
tf_resize_out = tf_resize_out.permute(0, 3, 1, 2).contiguous()

assert torch.max(abs(torch_resize_out - tf_resize_out)) < 1e-5
```

Comment: Grateful. You are right. It seems that the old version of tensorflow has a problem with this function, and the new version has the same result as torch